# SQL Server 2008 R2 CTP Installer crashes instantly after starting it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

I'm trying to update my existing SQL server 2008 SP1 installation with SQL Server 2008 R2 (November CTP).

I started the setup and chose the upgrade option and after some time the installer told me to reboot. As soon as I confirmed with OK, it crashed.

After rebooting I can't even run the setup file anymore. it crashes instantly without an error message.

What's the recommended way of troubleshooting this?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: You can't upgrade 2008 SP1 > 2008 R2.  Can you tell us your operating system and anything interesting that appears in the setup logs (this will be somewhere under C:\Program Files\ in a folder called Setup Bootstrap) or Windows Event Log (probably application).  Oh and I agree with Nick's re-tagging, this belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Try [enabling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) Windows Installer logging.

Comment: I just did, but there is no log file in temp after starting the installer. All I can see is a console window opening and closing again quickly.